# Preventing Leaks using RXJS combineLatest with pipe takeUntil

Tags: rxjs

When using Rxjs there's some confusion as to how the `takeUntil` operator behaves with `combineLatest` when using `pipe`.

Is it necessary to add `takeUntil` to each inner Observable like this including a piped `takeUntil`:

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs';
import {takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

---

```
combineLatest(
      this._store.pipe(select(stateOfLocation), takeUntil(this._destroy)),
      this._store.pipe(select(stateOfPlacesSelected), takeUntil(this._destroy))
    )
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
      .subscribe( ([location, places])  => {
        /* Business Logic */
      });
```

... or will the `pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))` handle the inner Observables from `combineLatest`, like this:

```
combineLatest(
      this._store.pipe(select(stateOfLocation)),
      this._store.pipe(select(stateOfPlacesSelected))
    )
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
      .subscribe( ([location, places])  => {
        /* Business Logic */
      });
```

My guess is the later is correct, but wanting to double check to make sure I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: When you use `takeUntil` after `combineLatest` it will complete the chain that will dispose and `combineLatest` will unsubscribe from all its source Observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: you do `takeUntil` exactly once. That's the point of the pattern: to keep it in a single place.

Once you `onNext(...)` on the `this._destroy$`, `takeUntil` is guaranteed to report completion, which, in turn, will trigger teardown logic (among which is unsubscribing).